# valueChanges method on carousel

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using reactive forms and on every valueChanges, i am sending post request.
i have a carousel which i  use in my form too and send the active item as an value in my forms.
now i want to do same valuechanges method on carousel.
this is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-on4rq3?file=app/app.component.ts)
how can i achieve that?

```
(this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
  .at(0)
  .valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.onSubmit();
    console.log("send form");
  });

  onSubmit() {
    this.data.firstName = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get("firstName").value;
    this.data.lastName = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get("lastName").value;
    this.data.Age = this.myCarousel.slideCounter + 3;
    console.log(this.data);

    // this.service.calculate(this.data).subscribe(
    //   (res:any)=>{
    //     console.log(res);
    //   },
    //   err => {
    //     console.log(err);
    //   }
    // );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that `carousel` element has a `transitionend` output event. You can use that to handle the event.

```html
 <carousel #myCarousel (transitionend)="transitionend($event)">
```

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-edt2l8?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts